Can’t Install the search-ads-360-python Library
I'm trying to connect with the SearchAds 360 API via a Python script. I'm following their quickstart guide and I’m having trouble installing the search-ads-360-python client library.
I've downloaded the file, and when I run the command pip install searchads360-py.tar.gz, I get the following error:
(sa360api) lenwood@Lenwood-MBP 2024.06.19_sa360-api % pip install searchads360-py.tar.gz
Processing ./searchads360-py.tar.gz
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-core<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (2.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=2.14.1 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (2.30.0)
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos>=1.53.0 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (1.63.1)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.10.0 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (1.64.1)
Requirement already satisfied: proto-plus<2.0.0dev,>=1.22.3 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (1.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0.dev0,>=3.19.5 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-api-core<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (4.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-api-core<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (2.32.3)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio-status<2.0.dev0,>=1.33.2 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (1.62.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=2.14.1->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (5.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=2.14.1->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=2.14.1->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.7.0,>=0.4.6 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3.0.0dev,>=2.14.1->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0.dev0,>=2.18.0->google-api-core<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=2.10.0->google-ads-searchads360==0.0.0) (2024.6.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: google-ads-searchads360
Building wheel for google-ads-searchads360 (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [42 lines of output]
    /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
    !!
    
            ********************************************************************************
            Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
            If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
            ********************************************************************************
    
    !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/3w/h_s63nl14p75qzww71xm_3fw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gwhvmyov/setup.py", line 56, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 102, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 75, in _install_setup_requires
        _fetch_build_eggs(dist)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 80, in _fetch_build_eggs
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 643, in fetch_build_eggs
        return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 832, in resolve
        dist = self._resolve_dist(
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 868, in _resolve_dist
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1155, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1170, in obtain
        return installer(requirement) if installer else None
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 106, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
        wheel.install_as_egg(dist_location)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 122, in install_as_egg
        self._install_as_egg(destination_eggdir, zf)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 130, in _install_as_egg
        self._convert_metadata(zf, destination_eggdir, dist_info, egg_info)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 175, in _convert_metadata
        os.rename(dist_info, egg_info)
    OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty: '/private/var/folders/3w/h_s63nl14p75qzww71xm_3fw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gwhvmyov/.eggs/libcst-1.4.0-py3.9-macosx-11.1-arm64.egg/libcst-1.4.0.dist-info' -> '/private/var/folders/3w/h_s63nl14p75qzww71xm_3fw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gwhvmyov/.eggs/libcst-1.4.0-py3.9-macosx-11.1-arm64.egg/EGG-INFO'
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for google-ads-searchads360
Running setup.py clean for google-ads-searchads360
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [42 lines of output]
    /Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:80: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
    !!
    
            ********************************************************************************
            Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
            If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
            ********************************************************************************
    
    !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/3w/h_s63nl14p75qzww71xm_3fw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gwhvmyov/setup.py", line 56, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 102, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 75, in _install_setup_requires
        _fetch_build_eggs(dist)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 80, in _fetch_build_eggs
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 643, in fetch_build_eggs
        return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 832, in resolve
        dist = self._resolve_dist(
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 868, in _resolve_dist
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1155, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1170, in obtain
        return installer(requirement) if installer else None
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 106, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
        wheel.install_as_egg(dist_location)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 122, in install_as_egg
        self._install_as_egg(destination_eggdir, zf)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 130, in _install_as_egg
        self._convert_metadata(zf, destination_eggdir, dist_info, egg_info)
        File "/Users/lenwood/opt/anaconda3/envs/sa360api/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 175, in _convert_metadata
        os.rename(dist_info, egg_info)
    OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty: '/private/var/folders/3w/h_s63nl14p75qzww71xm_3fw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gwhvmyov/.eggs/libcst-1.4.0-py3.9-macosx-11.1-arm64.egg/libcst-1.4.0.dist-info' -> '/private/var/folders/3w/h_s63nl14p75qzww71xm_3fw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gwhvmyov/.eggs/libcst-1.4.0-py3.9-macosx-11.1-arm64.egg/EGG-INFO'
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for google-ads-searchads360
Failed to build google-ads-searchads360
ERROR: Could not build wheels for google-ads-searchads360, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I've tried:

running pip install searchads360-py.tar.gz --use-pep517, it completes without error but the package doesn't show in either pip list or conda list and I get a ModuleNotFoundError when I try to import it.
unpacking the tarball, navigating to the folder and running python -m pip install ..
updating pip, setuptools and wheel to their latest versions
running this within Python 3.8.19, 3.9.19 and 3.10.14 environments
searching my system for the non-empty folder, the /private/var/folders/3w/h_s63nl14p75qzww71xm_3fw0000gn/T/pip-req-build-gwhvmyov folder doesn't exist.

My system is an M1 Mac with macOS Sonoma 14.5. Can anyone share guidance on how to resolve?

The important part of the error is above the part you have shown us, i,e., the part that the mentioned "subprocess" output.

Thank you Karl, your answer was helpful. I've updated the question to include the full error message. I now see that the issue is with deprecated packages and am researching PEP 517.

I did finally get this package installed and working. What wasn't clear to me is that searchads360-py.tar.gz is a package and util_searchads360_py.tar.gz is a collection of files. As such the util_searchads360_py files don't need to be "installed", they just need to be placed within the searchads360-py folder once that package is installed. I don't know if this is documented anywhere, a coworker pointed this out to me when he noticed that util_searchads360_py doesn't contain a setup.py file. I did have to use python -m pip install . --use-pep517 to complete the install. Here was my process.

Download both searchads360-py.tar.gz and util_searchads360_py.tar.gz to the target folder.

Open terminal and navigate to the folder. Activate the virtual enviroment where these are to be installed.

Enter the following commands in Terminal.
 % tar -xvzf searchads360-py.tar.gz
 % cd searchads360-py
 % python -m pip install . --use-pep517
 % cd ..
 % tar -xvzf util_searchads360_py.tar.gz


Copy all contents of the util_searchads360_py folder into the searchads360-py folder.


Once complete the folder structure will look like this (for brevity I'm not showing the contents of the sub-folders).
myVirtualEnv
|___searchads360-py
|   |___interceptors
|   |___build
|   |___tests
|   |___docs
|   |___scripts
|   |___google
|   __init__.py
|   config.py
|   client.py
|   mypy.ini
|   noxfile.py
|   setup.py
|   MANIFEST.in

The package is installed and ready to use.
    % python
    Python 3.11.9 | (main, Apr 19 2024, 18:34:54) [Clang 16.0.6 ] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from util_searchads360 import SearchAds360Client
    >>>

I can now import Python scripts using this library.
